# Why are animated calls of UIView.isHidden = false compounded?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

As you can see I'm having trouble formulating the question. Let me try to explain:

I'm using a search bar in my swift ios app. In order to get a desired animation effect I put it in a vertical stack view and then animate its `isHidden` property. This way search bar pushes down other children of the stack view as it animates in or pulls them up as it animates out. So far so good.

I've noticed a behavior that I think is strange. Could be a bug or could be me not understanding how things work. Basically if I call search bar hiding method x times in a row I need to call search bar showing method x times before it would show. I'd expect to have to make just one call to show search bar regardless of how many times I called hiding method. The issue doesn't exist other way around: if I call search bar showing code x times I only need to call hiding method once for it to go away. This doesn't happen if I set `isHidden` without animating it...

Here's a sample code and a video of the issue. I'd appreciate it if someone would help me understand this behavior.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar! {
    didSet {
        searchBar.isHidden = true
    }
}

@IBAction func showAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    expandSearch()
}

@IBAction func hideAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    collapseSearch()
}

private func expandSearch() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3){
        self.searchBar.isHidden = false
    }
}

private func collapseSearch() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3){
        self.searchBar.isHidden = true
    }
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}

}
```

[image: video]

Comment: `isHidden` should not be inside the animate but before it. and `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` should be inside the animate. you are animating the layout not the hidden value. this is happening because you're animating the wrong value

Comment: Where's your reference for that? I've never seen that it isHidden should NOT be in the closure.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call an asynchronous animation of searchbar x times, instead of I suggest you to keep its state in variable, something like isSearchBarHidden,
and check it before show/hide search bar. You could use just one method with such signature showSearchBar(show: Bool) and setting this variable there.

```
@IBAction func showAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    showSearchBar(true)
}

@IBAction func hideAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    showSearchBar(false)
}

private
func showSearchBar(_ show: Bool) {
    guard isSearchBarHidden != show else {
        return
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.searchBar.isHidden = show
    }) {
        self.isSearchBarHidden = show
        if !show && searchBar.isFerstResponder {
            searchBar.resignFirstResponder
        }
    }
}

private
var isSearchBarHidden: Bool = true
```

Also it is a good practice to check if your textView/textField/searchBar isFirstResponder before call resignFirstResponder.

Hope it will help. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Alex, I was capable of fixing the issue once I discovered it, the question here is why this is happening, not how to prevent it.